# When I run a Flask APP I get Webhook Method Not Allowed on Browser

Tags: python, flask

Hello this is the flask app code, when i try to run it on a browser with the /webhook added tot he .io address I get Method not Allowed, why is this??

```
import redis, sqlite3, time
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, g, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=5000, db=0)

conn = sqlite3.connect('trade.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS signals (
        timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        ticker,
        order_action,
        order_contracts,
        order_price
    )
""")
conn.commit()

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect('trade.db')
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def dashboard():
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM signals
    """)
    signals = cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template('dashboard.html', signals=signals)

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    data = request.data

    if data:
        r.publish('tradingview', data)

        data_dict = request.json

        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO signals (ticker, order_action, order_contracts, order_price) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        """, (data_dict['ticker'], 
                data_dict['strategy']['order_action'], 
                data_dict['strategy']['order_contracts'],
                data_dict['strategy']['order_price']))

        db.commit()

        return data

    return {
        "code": "success"
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run the flask app and go on google chrome with a ngrok .io link and try to add the "/webhook" i get the following message:

Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

Add `GET` to your allowed methods

```
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

Comment: It worked, now im getting this error:                                                                            
 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2021 17:10:05] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('*3')
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2021 17:10:05] "*3" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
[2021-09-01 17:10:05,900] ERROR in app: Exception on /webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Santiago\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Sa